# Microsoft Access report margins are set incorrectly, but only when they're created from my system

Tags: vba, ms-access, formatting, report, datasheet

Sometime after last Thursday morning (3/5/2020), the product datasheet that I've been automatically generating and printing for years from a VBA-enabled Access database now comes out with the margins set way too small, turning an 8.5 x 11 printout into ~4 x 11 printout (print preview shows the same).

The kicker is that nobody else is seeing this problem (it's a shared database). I even asked my IT manager to log in using my username/password on a physical system there within the company network (I work remotely) and the printout looks completely normal. He also VPN'd in from his own laptop using his login and mine...no problems.

This problem occurs in each of the following scenarios:

-local front-end, server back-end when logged into company network through VPN from my laptop

-server front-end, server back-end when logged into company network through VPN from my laptop

-local front-end, local back-end (on my laptop) with VPN enabled or disabled

-local front-end, server back-end using a remote connection to the physical system mentioned above (where it worked for the IT manager under my login)

-local front-end, server back-end using a remote connection to a different physical system located within the company network

-local front-end, server back-end using a remote connection to a virtual machine located within the company network (logged in under a completely username/password)

All systems are completely up to date with the most recent Microsoft Windows and Office updates.

What could be going on here? What should I try next?

Comment: Try to see what is setting of your Windows default printer under your profile. If you are using Win10 it will automatically switch/alter the default printer when you print from an application and Access uses that printer.

Comment: That was it! The default printer was not set yet under my profile and I'd been printing to a (newly installed) Zebra label printer during the day on Thursday. After manually setting the default to Adobe PDF, my datasheets print normally. Thanks Vlado.

Comment: You are welcome. I had the same problem. I am glad it was helpful - you can indicate it.

Comment: BTW: you can disable auto change of default printer in Win10 settings.

Comment: I want to indicate that your comment was helpful, but all I see to do is upvote. Also, on the auto-change, the "Let Windows manage my default printer" has never been clicked on (and remains unclicked). Yesterday when I went into the settings, there was no default printer set at all (the word Default was not under any printer in the list). Once I set Adobe PDF as the default, the word Default now appears under it. I'll be curious to see how my Zebra labels look with Adobe PDF set as the default. My code calls up the Zebra printer directly, so it should be fine...but we'll see.